# Allowing users access to SQLPLUS and to compile PLSQL

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, permissions

As a DBA - assuming my users are knowledgeable with PLSQL and SQL - why would I not grant my users privileges to compile and run their own PLSQL code. We have an MI database environment where the data has undergone ETL. The tables contain a large numbers of rows but not necessarily large rows in size. The analysis - will be - I assume of calculus in nature. The users are wanting to run their own code on the data for the purposes of ad-hoc analysis - within their own schemas. They come from a SAS background which from my understanding has allowed them to write and run their own analysis of data. Albeit, SAS runs on its own dataset - extracted from Oracle or elsewhere.

In my opinion this is a dangerous set-up - but without answering my own question - what are the pitfalls?